# Status bar заслоняет ToolBar

Tags: java, android

День добрый!

На некоторых устройствах Status bar заслоняет ToolBar?

В итоге Toolbar видно не полностью 
[image: Ущемленный Toolbar]

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Такое обычно бывает, когда для статусбара используется тема с прозрачностью

Comment: Посмотрите [этот вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28532054)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так :

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = toolbar.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        layoutParams.height = 46 + getStatusBarHeight();
        toolbar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        //для drawer
        drawellist.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0);
    }
```